# Where I can find restaurant data for android application?

Tags: web-services

I would like to know if there is a free api that would allow me to get restaurant information for an android application. The Application is supposed to search for nearby restaurants and display to the user. The problem is that there are some criteria that the restaurants must satisfy. The specific information I need is: location, type of food (mexican, italian, burger, etc.), type of restaurant (sit-down, fast food, buffet, etc.). Would there be any api that would give me these information? I know that I can use apis like Google custom search but the problem is that the result may not include all the information I want to have on every query( type of food, type of restaurant...)

thanks

Comment: Have a look at the Yelp API. http://www.yelp.com/developers

Comment: This isn't really an android question.  You're looking for a restaurant search web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, the Yelp! API allows you to filter based on a lot of [categories.](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/category_list) The other alternative would be the Google Places API, but that doesn't give you the sort of contextual information about the restaurant that you want.